# Generic Way to link slider and variable with Unity4.6 GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new to unity and c#

I try to find a way link sliders and variables of another script without having to code a little function (like this one) for each variables i need to update:

```
public Slider testSlider;
 void OntestSliderChanged() {
     someScript.someValue = testSlider.value;
 }//OR
public void OnhSliderChanged(float val) {someScript.someValue = val;}
```

I think i need to instantiate a slider (and i know how to do it) but when i need to add OnValueChanged listener 
i can't figure out how to link a given variable with the slider. 
Maybe i need to use a ref float and but OnValueChange take only one float argument. 
By the way my variables are statics float.

My issue seems so simple but i'm really lost right now.

Thanks and please excuse my poor English

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a bit more information - you have a slider, and you want to access it with other objects, right? Do you want to get notified when the value changes or will the other objects just read the value every now and then?

Comment: I want some statics variables for my DataScript to be equal to some sliders value. And sliders values to be equal to the DataScripts variable too. Basically i want to catch any changes on sliders and make my Data variables change.

Comment: Adding Listener doesn't actually work that way. If you want to make UI Dynamically and adding functionality to it. You need to add an Interface that is inside. UnityEngine Events Listener. For example IPointerClick and Drag and in your case... change value.